# I need help with Eagle CAD how do you edit silk screen how to add copper to the empty spaces

Tags: pcb-fabrication, eaglecad, cad

Like the title describes, these are two things I need to know how to do in eagle. 
Any pointers?

Thank you.

P.S. if anyone knows a tricky way to get an image into the silk screen it would be amazing.

Comment: "Like the title" question bodies (and thank you posts, by the way) are discouraged.  A better title would be "Silkscreen and copper pours for images in Eagle", and the body would explain whether you want to edit an existing package, packages currently in use, or a single PCB, whether the pour is to be applied to an image or a ground plane,etc.  **A title isn't long enough to contain all the information that's required for a complete question!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To import images as silkscreen (or any layer), use File->Run... and then choose import-bmp.ulp The image needs to be in BMP format. I'd recommend using a blank board to do this until you're sure it's correct, then doing a copy/paste into your actual board or better into a library instance.

To generate copper fill, use polygons. Use the Name command to assign them to the net you need.

Comment: These actions should be applied to a package (in a library), not saved as a PCB.